# Update an Umbraco document's CreateDateTime in Razor?

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to change the `CreateDateTime` for a node/document, but it doesn't appear to be having any effect. This is what I'm trying to far:

```
dynamic node = new DynamicNode(1065);                     
Document n = new Document(node.Id);
n.CreateDateTime = node.articlePublishedDate;
n.Save();
n.Publish(new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0));
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(n.Id);
```

Am I going about this in the right way? And also, am I correct in assuming that it can even be changed? The API seems to suggest the `CreateDateTime` has get/set, so it should work? Running the code through with breakpoints, it updates the `CreateDateTime`, but something with the save/publish seems to revert it back?

Comment: What version of umbraco is this?

Comment: @MortenOC this is Umbraco 7.1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is deprecated, so you need to use the "new" ContentService in umbraco:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService

It should be something like this:

```
var cs = Services.ContentService;
var node = cs.GetById(1065);
node.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
cs.SaveAndPublish(node);
```

Comment: Thank you @MortenOC. I couldn't seem to get the `SetValue()` to work with either `createDateTime` or `CreateDateTime`, but simply using `node.CreateDate` did the trick!

Comment: @edparry cool! I couldn't remember if CreateDate had a setter. But nice it worked! I've updated the answer.